# Skip Nullable int while parsing Json Response to C# object

Tags: c#, .net, nullable, jsonconvert

i'm parsing a json response to c# object

**My Model**

```
public class OutstandingPrompts
{
    public int? PatientID { get; set; }
    public int? AlertTypeID { get; set; }
    public int? PatientAlertID { get; set; }
    public int? PriorityID { get; set; }
    public string PriorityColor { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string AlertType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RecallDate { get; set; }
    public string ForSmoking { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string AlertValue { get; set; }
    public string AlertGroup { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EXPIRYDATE { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    public int? AlertCategory { get; set; }
    public int? IsConfidential { get; set; }
    public int? ConfidentialViewLogID { get; set; }
    public int? Completed { get; set; }
    public int? TotalRecords { get; set; }
}
```

**and here is how i'm converting it**

```
List<OutstandingPrompts> b = xs.Value.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(0).ToObject<List<OutstandingPrompts>>();
```

and **it is working fine** because i set the int type in my model as nullable int? as there is a possibility of null values for int type

now what i'm thinking, Is there a way to **parse the json without setting my int type as nullable**. one way i know of is to loop through the result at check if it is null it not then assign the value but is there **another way without writing your own logic??**

Comment: If your `int` properties are not nullable then they will be deserialized to 0. Is that what you want?

Comment: Using [NullValueHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) like `[JsonPropertyAttribute("myInt", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)] public int? MyInt { get; set; }`, will be good enought for Serialization. But Int cant be null. Any built-in integral numeric type will have 0 as default value.

Comment: What do you expect as value for the missing int property, after deserialization?

Comment: @mr.coffee yes exactly 0 or maybe -1

Comment: @DragandDrop if it's null 0 or -1